# FCM not seeing messages sent from spring backend app

Tags: java, android, spring, firebase, spring-boot

I have an android app configured under the Firebase Cloud Messaging, and when I send a notification from the console I see the notification in the Android app.

I am trying to now implement sending the notifications from a backend server java spring application, and here is my service to do so:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class FCMService {


    public void sendMessageWithData() throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageWithData();
        String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
        log.info("Sent message with data.");
    }


    private String sendAndGetResponse(Message message) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    }

    private AndroidConfig getAndroidConfig(String topic) {
        return AndroidConfig.builder()
            .setTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(2).toMillis()).setCollapseKey(topic)
            .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
            .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setSound("default")
                .setColor("#FFFF00").setTag(topic).build()).build();
    }

    private ApnsConfig getApnsConfig(String topic) {
        return ApnsConfig.builder()
            .setAps(Aps.builder().setCategory(topic).setThreadId(topic).build()).build();
    }

    private Message getPreconfiguredMessageWithData() {
        return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder().setTopic("all")
            .putData("test", "data")
            .build();
    }


    private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder() {
        AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig("all");
        ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig("all");
        return Message.builder()
            .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig)
            .setNotification(
                new Notification("sample title", "sample message"));
    }


}
```

The message is sent correctly, I get the id of the message in the response, but the notification is not visible in the app and I can't see it as a new notification in the firebase console. Where is the problem? Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can test your app sending a push notification with curl, with this you can validate if the problem is in your service or in your app

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "message":{
    "token":"TARGET_DEVICE_TOKEN",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Hello",
      "body":"This is a text message!"
    }
  }
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR-PROJECT-SHORT-NAME/messages:send
```

Comment: Do I always need a device token? How do I send a notifcation to all of the devices that are in my firebase project?

Comment: there're many ways to handle this, for example saving the token of each device in your db, there is a way to send push notification to all user, in that case is not necessary specific token

Comment: check here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics_2

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question: when I initialize my app on the server side and then fetch the firebase app instance I get an app named DEFAUL, do you know why this might happen?

Comment: I don't understand, where can you see this DEFAULT?

Comment: Nevermind, thank you for the help :) I guess you can't just send a notification to all devices, when i specified a topic and subscribed to it in the client mobile app it worked.